# Set no-touch option to Chrome OS emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Good morning. I need to test my application in Chrome OS, but without the "touch screen"

I used this guide to run a emulation of Chrome OS:

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/chrome-os-android-studio/

Ok, I succeeded to run it, I activated the debugging mode and I activated the adb debugging....finally everything is working and I can run my application on it.

The problem is, I want to test it without touchscreen.

I found the `hw.screen` property inside

```
~/.android/avd/<machine-name>.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
```

that was set to `hw.screen = multi-touch`.

WOW, exactly what I want, let's change it to `no-touch`.
Inside `~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/hardware-properties.ini` you can see

```
# Touch screen type
name        = hw.screen
type        = string
enum        = touch, multi-touch, no-touch
default     = multi-touch
abstract    = Touch screen type
description = Defines type of the screen.
```

so, `no-touch` is a valid option.

The problem is, even if I change it, every time I restart the emulator, it is set back to `multi-touch`.
I also tried to change the option directly in `~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/hardware-properties.ini`, that should contain the default option, but no luck...

Someone can tell me who is overwriting this property each time I start the emulation?

How can I remove the touch screen in the emulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the emulator from the command line and use the flag `-screen no-touch`. This is because the emulator overrides the config in the `.ini` file. That gives no touch screen but the mouse wasn't usable, at least on Windows.

[See the docs for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#common)

Comment: Thanks, that is the correct answer...Indeed without the mouse is a bit weird, but thanks :)